# Changing other child elements when hovering over first child using css

Tags: css, hover, css-selectors, parent-child

I am trying to affect the third child using hover on the first child of a div. Does anyone know of a way to do this just using css?

http://jsfiddle.net/boou28/fNxGa/

```
CSS

    /* works */
#firstp + p
{
background:#dddddd;
}

#firstp:hover + p
{
background:#ff0000;
}

#firstp + p + p
{
background:#dddddd;
}    

    /* doesnt work */

#firstp:hover + p + p
{
background:#ff0000;
}


HTML

<body>
<p>The first paragraph.</p>
<p>The second paragraph.</p>
<p>The third paragraph.</p>
</body>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/fNxGa/5/

Change your

```
#firstp:hover + p + p
```

to

```
#firstp:hover ~ p ~ p
```

`~` works the same as `+` selector, but `~` is less restrictive, as it selects any `p` that follows the hovered element. With `+` only the next sibling (after the hovered element) is selected.

Comment: Actually, the only reason why this works is because Chrome is buggy with `:hover` and `+`. In normal circumstances you should not have to change the `+` to `~` to get it to work, since `#firstp:hover + p + p` will still select the third `p` (and only the third `p`).

Answer (score 1):

I've commented out the

```
#firstp:hover + p
{
   background:#ff0000;
}
```

and it seems to be working (even without the comment):
**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fNxGa/2/)**

Comment: that's odd, I just opened your fiddle in fire fox and it works fine, but it doesn't work in chrome for me. thanks for the answer!

Comment: that's true... I've only tested in firefox... But [Jose's](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14973984/1581050) code works!